# How to change BottomSheet's animation speed?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I need to slow down the appearance of `BottomSheet`. I found `createAnimationController` method in `BottomSheet` class, but can't figure out how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the bottom_sheet.dart file, 
where after the import there is a field called duration.
giving you the sample data where you can change it.

const Duration _bottomSheetDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 200);

const double _minFlingVelocity = 700.0;

const double _closeProgressThreshold = 0.5;

you can change according to your needs
Let me know if it works

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm a bit confused. I should create a class which extends BottomSheet and I need to override duration field, right? What else should it contain?

Comment: Its on you how you  do it.

Comment: It appears that duration property affects only the modalBottomSheet but persistent one animates without changes.